# Tools to monitor performance on ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I am a looking for proven tools to monitor performance on ActiveMQ 5.5.  I come from an environment which used Glassfish and JMQ that can tell me rate of messages produced and consumed on any given destination using "imqcmd".  Is there a like tool for ActiveMQ or a different way to go about it?

I see that there is a project at http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-performance-module-users-manual.html that will do some sort of performance reporting but it seems to be no more than a SNAPSHOT version that I cannot get to operate.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are several options for this: [JMX](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html), [AMQ webconsole](http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html), [other options](http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-monitor-activemq.html)

here are my notes on this...I opted to go with JMX and built a simple web app (JSP, jQuery, Google Charts, etc) to interface with JMX to gather queue stats, manage queues, etc...

http://www.consulting-notes.com/2010/08/monitoring-and-managing-activemq-with.html